# Pulling link from HTML stored in array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pull a link from the following html. There's lots of bits of HTML like this one in an array.

tweets[0] is:

```js
var tweets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[class ^= AdaptiveMedia-ph]"));
console.log(tweets);
```

```html
<div class="AdaptiveMedia-photoContainer js-adaptive-photo " data-image-url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" data-element-context="platform_photo_card" style="background-color:rgba(51,64,18,1.0);" data-dominant-color="[51,64,18]">
  <img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" alt="A tree" style="width: 100%; top: -0px;">
</div>
```

How do I go about actually pulling the link in "src" and the alt text from "alt" from the HTML text? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the `src` and `alt` from the inner `<img>` tag?

Comment: Why use the Array.from() ?? Can we remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var tweets = document.querySelectorAll("[class ^= AdaptiveMedia-ph]");
for (var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++) {
  console.log("data-image-url",tweets[i].getAttribute("data-image-url"));
  var img = tweets[i].querySelector("img");
  console.log("image-url",img.src,"alt",img.alt);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="AdaptiveMedia-photoContainer js-adaptive-photo " data-image-url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" data-element-context="platform_photo_card" style="background-color:rgba(51,64,18,1.0);" data-dominant-color="[51,64,18]">
  <img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" alt="A tree" style="width: 100%; top: -0px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier if you would select directly the `img` elements and then just `.map()` the results:

```js
// Select img inside the cards
var tweets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[class ^= AdaptiveMedia-ph] img"));

var imgData = tweets.map(e => ({src: e.src, alt: e.alt}));
console.log(imgData);
```

```html
<div class="AdaptiveMedia-photoContainer js-adaptive-photo " data-image-url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" data-element-context="platform_photo_card" style="background-color:rgba(51,64,18,1.0);" data-dominant-color="[51,64,18]">
  <img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DfFmgY6WAAAh0sG.jpg" alt="A tree" style="width: 100%; top: -0px;">
</div>
```